# AssemblyVersion("1.0.*") one hour behind on the Revision value?

Tags: .net, time, assemblyversions

I'm using the following syntax to place into my assembly version's Revision value half the number of seconds in the day which have passed at the moment of compilation:

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

Windows Explorer shows the following two properties for the resulting assembly (XYZ is my doing and masks date information, which is irrelevant to my question):

File version: 1.0.XYZ.19527
Date modified: XYZ 11:50 AM

19527 times two comes to 10:50 AM -- why the one hour difference?

Comment: Is it possible that this is a UTC time and not the local time.
Suggestions: 1. give us additional information how are you passing time along to assembly version. 2. Try to change time zone and see if diff remains 1 hour. If not than it is very probably UTC staff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The revision number is not taking Daylight Saving Time offset into account.